# How do I invoke xargs with repeating arguments without a space between arguments

Tags: xargs

I am trying to diff two directories, and execute commands to copy missing files from one directory to another.

Here is my attempt at the command:

```
diff -r . $TARGET |
  fgrep \$1.class |
  awk '{ str = sprintf("%s/%s", $3, $4); sub(":","",str); sub("./","",str); print str;}' |
  xargs -I@ echo cp @ '$TARGET/' @
```

This currently results in this output:

```
cp validators/ProductControlsValidator$1.class $TARGET/ validators/ProductControlsValidator$1.class
```

If I remove the space after `'$TARGET/'`, then I get `$TARGET/@` (and the argument doesn't expand).

Fortunately, there were only a few missing files, so I did this manually.
I want to determine a command to generate and execute these copy commands so I could do this automatically in the future.

Please note that I have to keep the intermediate pathnames - it isn't just a filename.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when `rsync` can do the job?

Comment: fair point - rsync would probably solve my ultimate problem - but I'd still like to know if/how I could use xargs.

Comment: Use `${TARGET}` instead of `$TARGET`.